# Why does my regular expression fail with certain substitutions?

Tags: regex, perl

I am new to perl and not sure how to achieve the following.
I am reading a file and putting the lines in a variable called $tline. Next, I am trying to replace some character from the $tline.
This substitution fails if $tline has some special characters like (, ?,= etc in it. How to escape the special characters from this variable $tline?

```
if ($tline ne "") {

   $tline =~ s/\//\%;
}
```

**EDIT**

Sorry for the confusions. Here is what I am trying to do.

```
$tline =~ s/"\//"\<\%\=request\.getContextPath\(\)\%\>\//;
```

This is working for most of the cases. But when the input file has ? in it, it is failing.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Can you give us a sample of the data you're working with, and what you want it to become? What do you mean when you say the substitution "fails"?

Comment: Your regexp seems to be unclosed. `s/\//\%/`? Is it a typo? I'd suggest that if you have "/" in your expression you should use a different delimiter like : `s|/|%|`.

Comment: check my answer, updated with reference to quotemeta

Comment: Instead of `if($tline ne "")` I would use `if(length $tline)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about:

```
$tline =~ s/\Q$var\E/;
```

That will cause `quotemeta` to be applied to contents of `$var` which is being used as the pattern.

Comment: In my case, $var does not have any special characters but $tline has.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a valid regex:

```
$tline =~ s/\//\%;
```

It gets read like this to perl

```
$tline =~ s/a/%;
```

Where `a = /`

What you wanted to do is replace a *forward-slash* with a *percent sign* you probably want

```
$tline =~ s/\//%/;
```

Which is better written like this:

```
$tline =~ s,/,%,;
```

You probably also want to replace more than just the first forward-slash, so you want the `/g` flag:

```
$tline =~ s,/,%,g;
```

And, this exactly what `tr` (transliteration) does:

```
$tline =~ tr,/,%,;
```

**UPDATE** I think what you want is a simple `quotemeta()` which takes your input, and regex-escapes the meta characters

```
$ perl -e'print quotemeta("</foo?>")'
\<\/foo\?\>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could place all your special characters between square brackets (called a "character class").  The following will replace all left parentheses, question marks and equal signs in your string with percent signs:

```
my $tline = 'fo(?=o';
$tline =~ s/[(?=]/%/g;
print "$tline\n";
```

Prints:

```
fo%%%o
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, one way to do it is to put all the characters you want to replace in square brackets. Like so:

```
$string =~ s/[,?=\/]//;  # This will remove the first ',', '?', '=', or '/' from your string.
```

If you want to remove all the '?' in a string, for example, use a g on the end of it like so:

```
$string =~ s/[?]//g;
```

I'm a little rusty, but I believe that you only need a '\' in front of \ or /, (and of course the other special characters like \n,\t, etc...). Like so:

```
$string =~ s/[\\]/[\/]/g; # Switch from DOS to Unix delimiters.

$string =~ s/[\n\t]//g;   # Remove all newlines and tabs
```

As others have said, the code you've posted isn't going to work since you forgot the last /. That's another nice reason to keep the "weird" characters in a box.

Answer (score 0):

[`quotemeta`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#quotemeta)  is a good function for getting a exact literal with special characters into a regex. And [`\Q` and `\E`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlre#Escape_sequences) are good operators for doing the same thing inside the regex.

However, you're search expression is not that complex. In your edit, you're simply looking for a double quote and a slash. In fact, I've quite simplified your expression so it contains not a single *backslash*. So it's not a problem for [`quotemeta`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#quotemeta) nor for that matter [`\Q` and `\E`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlre#Escape_sequences).

Once pared down, I don't see anything in your revised substitution that would cause a problem with '?' in `$tline`.

Key to the simplification is that '.', '(', and ')' mean nothing special to the *replacement* section of your expression, so this is equivalent:

```
$tline =~ s/"\//"<%=request.getContextPath()%>\//;
```

Not to mention easier to read. Of course this is even easier:

```
$tline =~ s|"/|"<%=request.getContextPath()%>/|;
```

Because in Perl, you can choose the delimiter you wish with the [`s` *operator*](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlop#Quote_and_Quote-like_Operators____________________).

But with any of these, this works:

```
use Test::More tests => 1;

my $tline = '"/?"';
$tline =~ s|"/|"<%=request.getContextPath()%>/|;
ok( $tline =~ /getContextPath/ );
```

It passes the test. Perhaps you're having a problem with more than one substitution on a line. That can be fixed with:

```
$tline =~ s|"/|"<%=request.getContextPath()%>/|g;
```

That g is the *global* switch on the end, saying make this substitution for as many times as it occurs in the input.

However, since I can see what you are doing, I suggest an even tighter specification of what you want to search:

```
$tline =~ s~\b(href|link|src)="/~$1="<%=2request.getContextPath()%>/~g;
```

And when I run this:

```
use Test::More tests => 2;

my $tline = '"/?"';
$tline =~ s/"\//"<%=request.getContextPath()%>\//;
ok( $tline =~ /getContextPath/ );
$tline = 'src="/?/?/beer"';
ok( $tline =~ s~\b(href|link|src)="/~$1="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/~g
   );
```

I get two successes.

Your *true* problem is yet unspecified.