# Escaping double-quotes in the windows command prompt

Tags: windows, perl, escaping

I have a file with the following contents

```
$(CP) "$(O_SSL)" "$(INSTALLTOP)\bin"
$(CP) "$(O_CRYPTO)" "$(INSTALLTOP)\bin"
```

I want to add the following lines (order doesn't matter)

```
$(CP) "$(SSL).pdb" "$(INSTALLTOP)\bin"
$(CP) "$(CRYPTO).pdb" "$(INSTALLTOP)\bin"
```

So, using perl, I created the following command (which must be run from the command prompt):

```
perl -pi.bak -e 's#\t\$\(CP\) "\$\(O_([^)]+)\)" "\$\(INSTALLTOP\)\\bin"#$&\n\t\$(CP) "\$($1).pdb" "\$(INSTALLTOP)\\bin#g' ntdll.mak
```

But I just get the following error

```
Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1.
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

I tried replacing the single quotes with double quotes (and doubling all internal doublequotes) as so

```
perl -pi.bak -e "s#\t\$\(CP\) ""\$\(O_([^)]+)\)"" ""\$\(INSTALLTOP\)\\bin""#$&\n\t\$(CP) ""\$($1).pdb"" ""\$(INSTALLTOP)\\bin""#g" ntdll.mak
```

but I just get the following error instead

```
Substitution pattern not terminated at -e line 1.
```

How should I do this? (... I don't want to create a separate script file, but I'll do it if there's no other (reasonable) way)

Comment: Look into this [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html), May be this could solve your problem!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I escape special chars in a string I interpolate into a Perl regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156731/how-do-i-escape-special-chars-in-a-string-i-interpolate-into-a-perl-regex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked around the problem by using octal escapes for literal doublequotes

```
perl -pi.bak -e "s#\t\$\(CP\) \042\$\(O_([^)]+)\)\042 \042\$\(INSTALLTOP\)\\bin\042#$&\n\t\$(CP) \042\$(LIB_D)\\\$($1).pdb\042 \042\$(INSTALLTOP)\\bin\042#g" ntdll.mak
```