# Reading from log then deleting matching data in another file

Tags: bash

I want to write a script using Oscam Casrdsharing server

this is my test:

```
cat oscam.log | grep "error"
```

sample output:

```
2018/10/17 16:43:07 5C94A12E p    (cccam) cccam(r) test.dyndns.org: login failed, error
```

Once I've found an error, I need to remove its information inside another file :

oscam.server

```
[reader]
label                         = test.dyndns.org
protocol                      = cccam
device                        = test.dyndns.org,12000
key                           = 0102030405060708091011121314
user                          = renegade
password                      = renegade123
inactivitytimeout             = 30
group                         = 1
cccversion                    = 2.1.2
cccmaxhops                    = 0
cccmindown                    = 1
ccckeepalive                  = 1

blalbal
blalblalb
blalblalb
lablalb
```

I need to delete those "test.dyndns.org" lines that matched. I would like to keep only the following :

```
blalbal
blalblalb
blalblalb
lablalb
```

So far, I've tried the following code :

```
awk '/test.dyndns.org/{while(getline && $1 != ""){}}1' oscam.server

#output is :
[reader]

blalbal
blalblalb
blalblalb
lablalb
```

But the line `[reader]` is still present. What could I do to remove the block entirely?

Comment: Do you want to keep `[reader]` or delete it as well ?

Comment: yes also delete, i saw something this tried but not delete the.   [reader]    line    awk '/test.dyndns.org/{while(getline && $1 != ""){}}1' oscam.server.

Answer (score 1):

For your problematic, you are looking for a multi-line pattern that :

- begins by `[reader]`
- contains `test.dyndns.org`
- is followed by an empty line, i.e. 2 newline characters

You could use `perl` to do that :

```
perl -p0e 's/\[reader\]((?!\n\n).)*test\.dyndns\.org((?!\n\n).)*((\n\n)|(\n?\Z))//sig' oscam.server
```

`perl 's/.../.../s'` is a command to substitute the matched regex by another pattern, and the `ig` flags are used to removed every occurrences in your text input. Here, we replace the found pattern by an empty string.

The `-p0e` flags are used to enable multi-line processing for perl. You can use `-p0i.bak -e` for in-place file edition (be careful : it will permanently change your input file.)

`.`, `]` and `[` are escaped in the command because they have a specific meaning for regexes.

**Regex explanation :**

- `\[reader\]` : A pattern that begins by the "[reader]" string ...
- `((?!\n\n).)*` : [negative lookaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word). Followed by any characters that don't form 2 newlines ...
- `test\.dyndns\.org` : Followed by the string "test.dyndns.org" ...
- `((?!\n\n).)*` : Followed by any characters that don't form 2 newlines ...
- `((\n\n)|(\n?\Z))` : That ends by 2 newlines OR the end of the file

**Edit:**

To use a bash variable in a perl script, [you can use the -s flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321829/how-do-i-best-pass-arguments-to-a-perl-one-liner).

In order to automatically quote the content of a perl variable, you'll have to use the perl special characters : [\Q and \E](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156731/how-do-i-escape-special-chars-in-a-string-i-interpolate-into-a-perl-regex).

Your function will now look like this :

```
perl -sp0e 's/\[reader\]((?!\n\n).)*\Q$input\E((?!\n\n).)*((\n\n)|(\n?\Z))//sig' -- -input="<DESIRED INPUT HERE>" oscam.server
```

Comment: how do you format if variable the IP/dyndns address? because on perl reformat the text more difficult for bash integrating

Comment: @ZoltánVeres I edited my answer to address your comment. Let me know if it works for you !

Comment: nothing happened :(, only could on perl? not possible awk, sed, grep method?

Comment: @ZoltánVeres are you sure nothing happened ? Does the command show something ? By default in bash, a command will almost never modify your file. You'll have to use the `-i` flag or use stream redirection. Awk, sed, or other tools will work the same way, but will have a harder time dealing with multilines

Answer (score 0):

I made now finally a prompt method :), anyway dint want editing in-edit so need touch ***mv*** parameter after that

```
#!/bin/bash
PHONEFILE=/etc/tuxbox/config/oscam_modern/oscam.server
PHONEFILE2=/etc/tuxbox/config/oscam_modern/oscam.server.new 


read -p "Delete server (paste the url that was listed on top): " oldnum
if [ ! "$oldnum" ]; then exit; fi
perl -sp0e 's/\[reader\]((?!\n\n).)*\Q$input\E((?!\n\n).)*((\n\n)|(\n?\Z))//sig' -- -input="$oldnum" $PHONEFILE > $PHONEFILE2
mv $PHONEFILE2 $PHONEFILE
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is an easier way, only **NAME** parameter needs to be focused in the script now.

```
http://<IP>:<PORT>/oscamapi.html?part=readerlist&label=<NAME>&action=delete
```

This can be done without using perl.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31068519)